# Adding SearchField to StreamBuilder Reading from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a program that I get a list of users from Firebase's cloud Firestore, and display them in a Listview using a StreamBuilder in Flutter. The number of users will be large, and I want to implement a search field in my streambuilder that will query results that match my search field. I want it to look like this:

[image]

--photo credit: https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685

My Streambuilder that looks like the following:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    Text('Loading'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            default:
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.separated(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return buildUserRow(snapshot.data.documents[index]);
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Divider();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
          }
        })
```

So I want to use this StreamBuilder as my data source, and search by the Document Snapshot's `'name'` property. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually gets easy with Firestore

Add if condition on the string field. If it contains the search string, return widget.

This is not the final code, you will have to make many changes. But this is how it can be done.

```dart
ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (snapshot.data.documents[index].contains(youSearchString))
            return buildUserRow(snapshot.data.documents[index]);
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider();
        })
```

Comment: this way appears jerky, because everytime the user changes the textfield the setState method is called changing the ```searchString``` causing the app to have to reload the data from firestore

Comment: Same problem. I look to filter the data retrieved by StreamBuilder without recreating it. The setState method fires the stream query again.