# use StreamBuilder to fetch Firestore document which contains list of map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want read data from my firestore collection that has the format below

[image]

This is the class below. Don't Know how to use streamBuilder to read the documents. I also want a situation where I can pass a selected order to the next page. Thanks in advance.

```
class OrderModel2 {
  final String uid;
  final int subTotal;
  final String address;
  final String address2;
  final String zipCode;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final dynamic timeCreated;
  final String status;
  final List<OrdersList> orders;

  OrderModel2(
      {this.timeCreated,
      this.status,
      this.subTotal,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.zipCode,
      this.uid,
      this.address2,
      this.orders,
      this.address});

  OrderModel2.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String uid)
      : subTotal = data['subTotal'],
        address = data['address'],
        zipCode = data['zipCode'],
        phoneNumber = data['phoneNumber'],
        address2 = data['address2'],
        timeCreated = data['timeCreated'],
        status = data['status'],
        orders = data['orders'],
        uid = uid;
}

class OrdersList {
  final String productName;
  final String selected;
  final String image;
  final int price;
  final String category;

  OrdersList(
      {this.productName, this.selected, this.image, this.price, this.category});
  OrdersList.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)
      : productName = data['productName'],
        selected = data['selected'],
        image = data['image1'],
        price = data['newPrice'],
        category = data['category'];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `StreamBuilder` that you've written so far?

Comment: StreamBuilder<List<OrderModel2>>(
                stream: userRef.collection('Orders').snapshots().map(
                    (snapshot) => snapshot.documents
                        .map((doc) =>
                            OrderModel2.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID))
                        .toList()),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would use SteamBuilder to access the documents within the Orders Collection.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Orders').snapshots(),
  builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
    ) {
  if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("products").snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return !snapshot.hasData
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                return YourObject(
                  documentSnapshot: data,
                  paramI: data.documentID,
                  paramField: data['field'],
                );
              },
            );
```

Definitely read this to get a whole picture of what's happening !
https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-firebase-firestore-in-flutter-b0ea2c62bc7

Also here is a StackOverflow about adding a searchfield also!
[Adding SearchField to StreamBuilder Reading from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829119/adding-searchfield-to-streambuilder-reading-from-firestore)

Comment: Can you provide the full code where listview builder was used?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Glad I could help!